# href tag redirect to page and OnGet is called twice but the second time with wrong value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor, href

So this is my a tag:

```
<a href="/Text/@text.Id" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>
```

This is my OnGet method who is called twice:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(Guid Id)
    {
        TextPost = await _textPostRepository.GetAsync(Id);

        if (TextPost.Tag.TagManagement.RestrictedToMembers)
        {
            if (!_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/AccessDenied");
            }
        }

        return Page();
    }
```

So first time the Id is the right. But second time the Id (who is a Guid) is: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000!
The page is finally rendering fine but when I am in debug mode it makes an error. Have you any idea?

Comment: Is there any other markup that could be accidentally calling your anchor tag? Maybe some javascript code is invoking the event twice.  You can try changing your tag to this:  `<a href="@Url.Action("OnGet", "{ControllerName}", new { Id= text.Id});" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>` and see if that works for your case

Answer (score 0):

> OnGet is called twice

I guess you may put this href at the Text.cshtml, then call OnGet in  Text.cshtml.cs, so it will call the  OnGet twice.

> but the second time with wrong value

You need to pass  the data parameter correctly,
try the below code:

```
<a href="/Text?Id=@text.Id" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>
```

or

```
<a asp-page="Text" asp-route-Id="@text.Id" class="btn btn-dark">Lire</a>
```